NonLinearModelFit with multiple y-values for some x-values
I am fitting to a set of measurements, where for some x-values there are multiple datapoints {{x,y1}, ..., {x,y2}...} from different measurements. Is this a problem for Fitting with NonlinearModelFit?
Edit: It seems to run, the question is if this is basically the same as having data for two different x-values, or if you have to be cautious with this.

What did you try so far?

Why don't you just try it and see?

It depends on how those multiple data points arose. NonlinearModelFit only allows one error term (with errors being independent).  If, for example, the multiple measures arise from sampling the same experimental unit more than once, then you have a "mixed" model with two error terms.  Alternatively, you should look at estimating what is called "pure error" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lack-of-fit_sum_of_squares).  See a statistician or ask this at CrossValidated (https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Yes I tried it out already, and it runs. The question was indeed more about what that implies for the fitting algorithm and if the resulting fit should be viewed with caution.

To clarify:  if the model and error structure that generates the data has independent errors (either with a common variance or known weights), then NonlinearModelFit will produce appropriate estimates.  If the errors are correlated (as when the same experimental unit has multiple measurements), then NonlinearModelFit will not produce appropriate measures of precision (standard errors for parameters and error variances).  However, NonlinearModelFit will produce ouput (good or bad) in either case.


Is this a problem for Fitting with NonlinearModelFit?

No. If you study the general formulation of the least-squares problem, you'll see that none of the formulas assume distinct $x$-values.
Let's try it out:
data = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 7}, {3, 0}};

LinearModelFit[data, {1, x}, x]
(*    FittedModel[4.5 - 1. * x]    *)

NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b x, {a, b}, x]
(*    FittedModel[4.5 - 1. * x]    *)


It is true that NonlinearModelFit will give output without error messages when there are multiple response observations for a predictor value .  But it is not true that the resulting fit and diagnostic statistics output are necessarily appropriate.  That depends on the error structure of the model and, of course in all cases, the model.

@JimB of course, all these tools have sharp edges and the novice can (and does) run into misuse them if edge cases aren't well understood. As you comment, the broader topic of "what does this mean" may be for a graduate-level statistics course; but here the question was only about whether or not the tool works at all in this case.

However, I don't think having duplicate or even multiplicate $x$-values is a problem a priori: just have a look at the general formulations, which are totally well behaved in these cases.

Thanks to both of you. What is done is basically a least square fit (weighted by errors) with NMinimize and I wanted to know if this really clean mathematically. But right now I tend to agree that this fitting procedure should not run into problems.
